# Preventing Text Submission In Controller Failing

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angularjs

I'm running a simple example from the main page of Angular involving a todo list. I want to prevent the user from submitting a todo when the input field is blank. The problem is when I load the page and the first thing I do is I click inside the input field and press enter, then the blank todo is added the Todo list. However, after that the validation works. I know there are other ways of doing this, but I want to know why this bug exists and how to fix it.

My html below

```
<form ng-submit="addTodo()">
  <input ng-model="todoText" placeholder="Add a todo here" type="text" />
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="add">
</form>
```

My js file

```
$scope.addTodo = function() {
  var text = $scope.todoText;
  if (text != "") {
    $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.todoText, done:false});
    $scope.todoText = '';
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$scope.todoText` is `undefined` , so it passes your condition and then is set to empty string `''`, based on your model's variables

either do `if (!$scope.todoText) {` or initialize it to empty string `$scope.todoText = '';`

in controller:

```
$scope.todoText = '';

$scope.addTodo = function() {
  if ($scope.todoText != "") {
    $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.todoText, done:false});
    $scope.todoText = '';
  }
};
```

Comment: Actually, your code doesn't work. I thought your answer made sense but now that I tested it's still acting the same.

Comment: Declaring `$scope.todoText` as a variable then checking the variable within the if statement proved futile as the bug still exists. My code is updated.

Comment: setting `$scope.todoText = '';` in your controller will initialize it to empty string. You should initialize your model in the controller and not in the addTodo function.. I added some code above

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `required` attribute in the input?

```
<input type="text"
       ng-model="todoText"
       required <------------- prevents submission and marks the view as invalid
       size="30"
       placeholder="add new todo here" />
```

Have a try at http://jsfiddle.net/hbulhoes/uBXfN/